# this.state is undefined in render and componentWillMount

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native. I had defined a flag. But when I printed it render and  componentWillMount  it initially shows undefined and later changed it's state as true/false. Someone please help.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
         flag: data ? true : false
    };
}

    componentWillMount() {
        console.log("Flag Status:", this.state.flag)
        }
    render(){
     console.log("Flag Status:", this.state.flag)
      }
```

Comment: Whta is `data` here ?

Comment: @user9384077 you will get data from api?

Comment: I'll get data from previous screen. If data is present I'll set flag to true else false

Comment: Are you passing in the data as props?

Comment: @AdamJohnston Yes

Comment: Try not setting this.state.flag until everything is mounted by doing `componentDidMount() { this.setState( { flag: this.props.data ? true : false } ) }`

Comment: @AdamJohnston It still shows undefined for first time when called inside render()

Comment: can you please check console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.date) weather you are getting the data from from previous screen through navigation params ?

Comment: @SathvikNasani Yes, there was issue with data in previous screen. Now fixed it.

Comment: @user9384077 now issue resolved?

Comment: @SathvikNasani Yes